# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 6233: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm working on a new project but I can't fix the error in the title.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5.2

import urllib.request , urllib.parse


def start(url):
    source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    info = urllib.parse.parse_qs(source_code)
    print(info)


start('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfRLJQlpMNw')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurred because of .encode which works on a unicode object. So we need to convert the byte string to unicode string using

```
.decode('unicode_escape')
```

So the code will be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5.2

import urllib.request , urllib.parse


def start(url):
    source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    info = urllib.parse.parse_qs(source_code.decode('unicode_escape'))
    print(info)


start('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfRLJQlpMNw')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self explainatory: there is a byte 0xf0 in an input string that is expected to be an ascii string.

You should have given the exact error message and on what line it happened, but I can guess that is happened on `info = urllib.parse.parse_qs(source_code)`, because `parse_qs` expects either a unicode string or an ascii byte string.

The first question is why you call `parse_qs` on data coming from youtube, because the doc for the Python Standart Library says:

> Parse a query string given as a string argument (data of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Data are returned as a dictionary. The dictionary keys are the unique query variable names and the values are lists of values for each name.

So you are going to parse this on `=` and `&` character to interpret it as a query string in the form `key1=value11&key2=value2&key1=value12` to give `{ 'key1': [ 'value11', 'value12'], 'key2': ['value2']}`.

If you know why you want that, you should first decode the byte string into a unicode string, using the proper encoding, or if unsure `Latin1` which is able to accept any byte:

```
def start(url):
    source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('latin1')
    info = urllib.parse.parse_qs(source_code)
    print(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is rather weird indeed. You are using query parser to parse contents of a web page.
So instead of using parse_qs you should be using something like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html).